# Unity build error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1"

Tags: unity, android

I'm getting this error when trying to build my game for Android, I've googled it but there's only 1 result about it and it didn't work for me as I use 64-bit windows. How can I fix this and what's causing it?

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1
>   System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidComponentProperties.Read (System.String directory) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidComponentProperties.GetPackageRevision (System.String directory) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.BuildToolsVersion () (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKBuildToolsDetector.GetVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector detector) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:106)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> Error building Player: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Unity/Visual Studio and installing them again fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

restarting unity fixed the problem for me